# Finding the specific Tag a

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

My HTML is:

```
<a id="showSlotsByLocation_" href="#" style="color:blue;" onclick="confirmAppt('28/05/2013','364301');">14.00 - 14.15</a>
<a id="showSlotsByLocation_" href="#" style="color:blue;" onclick="confirmAppt('28/05/2013','364303');">14.15 - 14.30</a>
```

Id name are same on all links. This is the main difficulty.

I want to click second link my javascript code are configure web browser is

```
if (location.pathname == "/abc")
{
    //alert('location found') this is ok found;

    var el = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i=0;i<el.length;i++)
    {
        if (el.id == 'showSlotsByLocation_' && el.innerText.isEqual('14.15 - 14.30') && el.outerHTML.contains("confirmAppt('28/05/2013'"))
        {
            alert('link found') \\this condition not match;
            el.onclick();
        }

    }
}
```

What do i do to match the condition?

Comment: is `isEqual()` and `contains()` custom functions, as I don't anything like that exists natively ?

Comment: Having more than one of the same ID on an HTML page is a violation of the spec, so if you're in charge of the HTML (or know the person who is) you should get that changed. Second, along with what @adeneo is saying, you should really be doing `el.innerText === '14.15 - 14.3'` (as well as using `===` in the first comparison for consistency/good form).

Comment: consistency or good form has nothing to do with whether or not to use two or three equal signs as a comparing operator, whether or not to match both type and value is the only thing that's really important, and you don't use three equalsigns everywhere just to be consistent?

Comment: @adeneo It's fair to say that consistency is definitely not the *only* reason to do it. By "good form" I was meaning "best practice" more broadly, and I use `===` everywhere, because I think it's a bad idea to compare the values of things that aren't the same type. It's confusing at *best*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have two element with the same ID, IDs are unique.

When you will have changed the IDs, you'll can access them simply using  `document.getElementById('idOfYourElement')`

EDIT:
First of all, you need to declare a "current" variable that takes the current element in the loop, you can't use `el.id` because `el` is a collection of HTMLElements! I'm sorry I didn't noticed it before.
So you need this(define the variable **inside** the for loop, just before the if statement):

```
var current = el[i];
```

Now that you have defined it, change this whole line with the code below.

```
if (el.id == 'showSlotsByLocation_' && el.innerText.isEqual('14.15 - 14.30') && el.outerHTML.contains("confirmAppt('28/05/2013'"))
```

> I think this is the code that stops you. There are no functions called `isEqual` and `contains` in JS.

```
if (current.id == 'showSlotsByLocation_' && current.textContent === '14.15 - 14.30' && current.outerHTML.indexOf("confirmAppt('28/05/2013'") !== -1)
```

One last thing: innerText isn't a valid cross browser property, use textContent instead.

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FNode.textContent)

**Updated JS code**

```
if (location.pathname == "/abc")
{    
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i=0;i<el.length;i++)
    {
        var current = el[i];
        if (current.id == 'showSlotsByLocation_' && current.textContent === '14.15 - 14.30')//I'm not sure about this one, in case you want it just remove the comment and the last parenthesis && current.outerHTML.indexOf("confirmAppt('28/05/2013'") !== -1)
        {
            alert('link found');
            current.click();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: id are same, on website. this the main difficulty.

Comment: Nicely observed, but as the selection happens on tagNames, it's probably not the issue, and should have been a comment in my opinion!

Comment: Isn't the website yours? Then find a way to change them and you'll be okay.
@adeneo I'm updating the answer, you're right!

Comment: A website give only 2 second for click this so i want the help of my webbrowser and javascript to find the link and click this.

Comment: Then report them they have invalid HTML pages. Anyway, I updated the code, I don't know if it'll work because I don't know the HTML source, so I can't tell you if the outerHTML condition is right(at first sight, it isn't, you should try to remove it and keep only the textContent one.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer again, noticed something really stupid. Try out the last version, I put inside the whole code!

Comment: You can remove the link. Updated the code, you were calling the wrong function!